# peer to peer (p2p) connection between smart tv and smartphone

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, webos

So, I program for a couple of years now and I only programmed websites. However, I wanted to make a Web App for my LG TV and already downloaded the SDK, ide, emulator, etc.. And it was pretty easy to get a basic App that works fine. I also used PhoneGap (used to make mobile apps with HTML, CSS, js, node js) to do the same App for my android phone.

So my problem is that I need a way to get **p2p (peer to peer) connections between my tv and my smartphone.** I want to do a simple game, where the tv is used as a monitor and the phone as a controller. However, I don't want to use a web server. You should be able to play it, without an internet connection, but with a wifi network.

I already looked for **WebRTC**, but I didn't understand how it works, to be honest. I also read something about **socket io**. From what I have understood is, that the tv needs to run an HTTP-server and then the phone needs to connect to it? But then, the smartphone somehow needs to know the IP of the HTTP-server. Otherwise, you would have to type the IP every time you want to play.

I don't need a finished code, just a point where I can start and an explanation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, there is something called ConnectSDK which solves my problem (It works not only with LG TV's but also with 7 different platforms). The SDK is made by LG, however it took me 8 months to find it.

Why? Because LG is not telling you about this SDK on their own page for TV developers... Even though creating a websocket server on the phone and make the TV join this server by manually typing the ip works, however ConnectSDK provides a much better user experience.

It feels like they don't want that people programm good apps for their TV's.

LG communication skills: 1/10

Answer (score 0):

Given the specifics of the project (small lan), to bypass the necessity of inputing an ip adress, i usually do :

1- Retrieve the phone ip address and subnet with phonegap js api;

2- Scan the subnet range for http server with a predefined route to identify the smart tv app(at most 255*255 adress to scan for big lan; with js its easy to parallelise hundreds/thousands of simultaneous requests);

----> this route should output something readable identifying the appliance, in case of multiple results.

3- Display the list of results on the phone; retrieve user input; then connect.

You need to use websockets (hence, why not socketio implementation) to be able to do real time interaction with small delay given the parameters of your project.

Enjoy !

Comment: Turns out that it is not really possible on "modern" LG TV's. The only way to do it, is to run a server on the phone (with socket.io Java) and use the socket.io JS to connect the Tv to the phone. However, to be able to do that, you need to manually type in the IP of the phone on the TV. 

The LG TV that came out 2019 still uses software that is made in 2013. (RIP my life)